# XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, file-exists

So I'm building a jQuery plugin to swap out normal graphics for retina ones when the user is on a high-pixel-density device. Part of that swap required checking if the retina version of the file exists at a certain url around the web. Here's how it checks:

```
function urlExists(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status!=404;
};
```

But when it tries to check a file that is on a different server then the current one, it fails with this error in the console:

`XMLHttpRequest Exception 101: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.`

How can I allow cross-domain XML https requests so that this works on any site that loads the plugin?

Also, I'd like to eventually convert this to JS, so doing it without jQuery would be optimal.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JacksonGariety/7YYgP/1/
(NOTE: I've commented out the check for retina devices portion so you can test stuff)

Comment: From what it looks like though, you're not performing any jQuery at all. At least with the code you've provided.

Comment: If you check the jdFiddle, there's a bit of jQuery mixed in here and there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing cross-domain AJAX requests depends on the *server* configuration, not the *client* (as best I know). That means that there's no way to ensure a successful / allowed cross-domain AJAX request just from loading a jQuery / JS plugin alone.

If there is, though, golly, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: I'm not much of a CoffeeScript person, but from what I can see, this is definitely sending an XHR, but is limited to the current document's domain? [It's jumping ship if it detects that the image is in an external server](https://github.com/imulus/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina_image_path.coffee#L18) (line 18-26).

Comment: I believe the answer is incorrect - cross-domain AJAX requests depends on the client.  When you make the request from client to server, the server doesn't care that you're from a different IP address (since that is most of the internet!).

Comment: @badunk ~ True, XS AJAX restrictions are primarily on *client*; but if you're authoring a plugin, you can't expect to instruct your web users to *hey, make sure you've got XS enabled on your browser before browsing this site! Just go Tools > Settings ... blah*. Barring that, the only (viable?) ways to allow XS (even pseudo forms) is through JSONP or CORS, both of which rely on some sort of pre-existing server configuration / preparedness.